# Sharepoint LINQ The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System'

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

I have sharepoint Foundation 2010 installed in my Win7 Home premium 64 bit laptop.

I used layouts folder to copy my aspx pages which has two imports using using System.Linq;,Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq;I am getting this error

The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?) But even adding the following lines as suggested in many forums

I changed the web.xml file available under C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80 to add the following content

```
    <add assembly="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
    <add assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Search, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />


    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>

  </assemblies>
```

and this before  `</configuration>`

```
<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
        <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
            <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
        </compiler>
        <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
            <providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true"/>
            <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
        </compiler>
    </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```

Please Guide

Answer (score 2):

I checked this on my work box: All you need to include in the web.**config** is the *System.Core* assembly and a `compiler` element with the *CompilerVersion* set to "v3.5".

This goes into *Configuration/system.web/compilation*:

```
<assemblies>
  <add assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
  <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  <add assembly="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
  <add assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Search, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
  <add assembly="Microsoft.Office.Access.Server.UI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
  <add assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
  <add assembly="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />

  <!-- Additional Assembly -->
  <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
</assemblies>
```

This goes into */Configuration/*:

```
<system.codedom>
  <compilers>
    <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5" />
      <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false" />
    </compiler>
  </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```

The assemblies *System.Data.Linq* and *System.Data.Linq* are not required.

Comment: Thanks! But even after adding it and reset its not working .Suggestions please?

Answer (score 1):

Found It ! Since its aspx deployed in layouts folder , the web.config in layouts folder has to be changed as Suggested above. Thanks All