# Why do I not need to add <%@ Import namespace="System.Linq" %> before using Linq in my aspx pages

Tags: asp.net, linq

A customer is experiencing an error in our web app - the full stack trace is at the bottom but the exception message is

```
   System.Web.HttpParseException (0x80004005): e:\inetpub\wwwroot\Application\Mycontrol.ascx(19): error CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<MyClass>' does not contain a definition for 'ToArray' and no extension method 'ToArray' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<MyClass>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

And sure enough, there is code in the markup like this

```
   <%# MyList.ToArray() %>
```

And there is no import directive at the top of the page to import `System.Linq`.  So I can kind of see where the exception is coming from but (in classic developer style) it works on my machine!  It also works on every other server that the software has been installed on.

I double checked my `web.config` that it was not including the `System.Linq` using a system.web/pages/namespaces element (and I also checked the applicationHost.config).  There is no mention of `.Linq` in either file.

**Edit #1**

As a quick check I have created a new .Net 4 web application in VisualStudio.
The vanilla web.config does not mention `System.Linq` or `System.Core.dll`.  (Neither do my applicationHost.config or machine.config files).

I added this bit of linq code to Default.aspx

```
<%= new[] {"harp", "plinth", "uncanny", "donkey"}.ToArray().Count() %>
```

without adding any Import directive.  And I got '4' on the screen - which means that the correct linq code is running.

So somehow System.Core.dll is being included as a reference and the `System.Linq` namespace is being imported during compilation of this page (apparently by magic!)

**Edit #2**

Our support guy has just reported that adding

```
 <%@ Import namespace="System.Linq" %>
```

into the errant page fixes the problem.
So I conclude from that that the problem is confined to the `System.Linq` namespace not being imported 'automagically' on the customer's machine (as it is on mine and every other machine) and not anything to do with the System.Core.dll not being available during the page compilation.

So my question is twofold - can someone explain why it works on my machine and why it may be failing on the customer's.

```
    System.Web.HttpParseException (0x80004005): e:\inetpub\wwwroot\Application\Mycontrol.ascx(19): error CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<MyClass>' does not contain a definition for 'ToArray' and no extension method 'ToArray' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<MyClass>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) ---> System.Web.HttpCompileException (0x80004005): e:\inetpub\wwwroot\Application\Mycontrol.ascx(19): error CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<MyClass>' does not contain a definition for 'ToArray' and no extension method 'ToArray' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<MyClass>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.PostProcessFoundBuildResult(BuildResult result, Boolean keyFromVPP, VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetBuildResultFromCacheInternal(String cacheKey, Boolean keyFromVPP, VirtualPath virtualPath, Int64 hashCode, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultFromCacheInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.UI.BaseTemplateParser.GetReferencedType(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean allowNoCompile)
   at System.Web.UI.BaseTemplateParser.GetUserControlType(VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.UI.MainTagNameToTypeMapper.ProcessUserControlRegistration(UserControlRegisterEntry ucRegisterEntry)
   at System.Web.UI.BaseTemplateParser.ProcessDirective(String directiveName, IDictionary directive)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding fileEncoding)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessException(Exception ex)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding fileEncoding)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseFile(String physicalPath, VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.Parse()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BaseTemplateBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider buildProvider)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp)
   at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Do you have that import directive in your web.config?

Comment: No - sorry I should have mentioned that my web.config has no <namespaces> element and I have also checked the aplicationHost.config for that too.

Comment: Then I guess the web.config for that computer is good (= it contains the reference for System.Linq) and it has the proper framework version installed.

Comment: "It also works on every other server that the software has been installed on." points to a server configuration issue. I'd check the .Net version on the server, and the IIS settings against a working server to make sure there's nothing amiss

Comment: Have you checked that the namespace is not in your machine.config?

Comment: The System.Core assembly has to be included in the web.config in order to use linq in inline code => [LINQ The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System'](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10682154/181108)

Comment: @Joel: Yup I have checked the machine.config on my machine.

Comment: @DarkHippo: The application is a .Net4 app so I would be surprised if it ran at all if the wrong .Net version was being used. (Otehr pages run fine BTW).  I agree - it definitely is a server config issue.  I am trying to work out what to tell the support guy he should be checking (i.e. which config file / setting to double check)

Comment: @Stefan.  Thank you for that link.  I don't think including System.Core is necessary for .Net 4 (I may be completely wrong but a quick test app seems to confirm my suspicions - see edit in question)