# System.Linq without Array.Contains

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, runatserver

I included in `Global.asax` the following:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Linq" %>
.
.
.
<script runat="server">
   MyLib.ReturnArray().Contains(<value>);
</script>
```

Still, I received the infamous `System.Array does not contain a definition for 'Contains'...`

Why wouldn't it work?

**PS**

Might be connected to [this (unanswered) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736008/why-do-i-not-need-to-add-import-namespace-system-linq-before-using-linq). Maybe details there could help answer this one.

Comment: Post the full compiler error. It seems you're trying to invoke a overload which doesn't exist at all

Answer (score 1):

`Contains` expects an element you're looking for, not a lambda. Use `Any` to check if there is at least one element matching a predicate.

Answer (score 0):

Contains Determines whether the specified object exists as an element

The Contains method accepts a single parameter: the searched-for element. 
The LINQ Contains method accepts two parameters, with an additional IEqualityComparer instance that specifies how elements are compared for equality.

MSDN REF [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384015.aspx) ,
[Ref2](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list-contains)